# Select a pseudo-element

Tags: javascript, pseudo-element

I recently needed to do [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) and [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to get the exact float pixel values of its position and size since it was positioned absolute from a viewport ([vw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Syntax)) relative positioned `input` and it was too confusing for me to guess.

The way I did to do that was with [`$0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) (I'm using Google Chrome's Developer Tools console) which returns the currently-inspected element in the page.

```
window.getComputedStyle($0);
$0.getBoundingClientRect();
```

**My question is** how can a pseudo-element be targeted with JavaScript?

I tried to get it by using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) but got no success:

```
document.querySelector('::after');
document.querySelector('*::after');
document.querySelector('input::after');
document.querySelector('input > *');
document.querySelector('input[type=radio]::after');
```

After that I searched but the only thing that I found was a way to get the properties:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('input'), '::after').getPropertyValue('color');
```

[Source](https://davidwalsh.name/pseudo-element)

Comment: I closed this even though the related post is for JQuery. The answers/comments in that post explain that it can't be done directly, but do talk about work arounds.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I guess there's really no way since the workarounds are to change/get/set the properties. So there's no way to for example [log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) `::after` as if it was an element just like it does with `console.log($0);`.